# PHP Unable to load stream googlemaps API

Tags: php, mysql

I'm try to use googlemaps API into a user profile registration page.
Part of code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    }

    .
    .
    .

if($address !=''){
    $address_code = urlencode($row['address']);
    $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address_code."&sensor=true";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
    $status = $xml->status;
    if ($status=="OK"){
      $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
      $lng = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
      $latlng = "$lat,$lng";
    }
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO users(lat,lng) VALUES('$lat','$lng')";
    mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
.
.
.
```

When I send the registration, it returns me an error 
"[function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream".
It seems that the API call is not able to read the contents of the 'address'.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: you need to urlencode $address_code variable. not mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
file_put_contents('update.xml', file_get_contents('http://someurl.com/update.xml')
);

$xml = simplexml_load_file('updated.xml');
```